# Coloring row in ListView for the given from object color

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I have a ListView in which I display the list of objects of a given type. One of the properties of the object is color. Is there a way to color each row on a given color, or else to show it in any graphical way? For now, I've only figured out how to show a color string in a separate column.
Object:

```
public class Parcel
{
    public int parcelId { get; set; }
    public int sizeX { get; set; }
    public int sizeY { get; set; }
    public int positionX { get; set; }
    public int positionY { get; set; }
    public int area { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }

    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public Parcel(int id, int sX, int sY, int pX, int pY)
    {
        parcelId = id;
        sizeX = sX;
        sizeY = sY;
        positionX = pX;
        positionY = pY;
        area = sX * sY;
        color = Color.FromRgb((byte)rnd.Next(0, 256), (byte)rnd.Next(0, 256), (byte)rnd.Next(0, 256));
    }
}
```

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewParcelsInContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="201" Margin="115,309,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID PACZKI" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding parcelId}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Szerokość (w cm)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sizeX}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Długość (w cm)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sizeY}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Powierzchnia(w cm^2)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding area}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Kolor" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding color}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: We need to see your code. As far as I can tell when you use `Binding` and the Property type matches desired target `Background` there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ListViewItem` Style:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewParcelsInContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="201" Margin="115,309,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID PACZKI" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding parcelId}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Szerokość (w cm)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sizeX}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Długość (w cm)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sizeY}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Powierzchnia(w cm^2)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding area}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Kolor" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding color}">
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```